# OpenCl header cl.h not found VS2019 ComputeCpp in SYCL/include_opencl.h

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2019, sycl

**QUESTION 1 (TEMPORARLY SOLVED USING Vcpkg)**

I have read through all similar/related Questions but I'm at a loss here - I used Cmake to build the VS2019 project files for the ComputeCpp samples according to the Guide (https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides).

I'm not incredibly familiar with Cmake but I've managed to generate them using the Cmake GUI rather than the command line, setting all flags, such as the OpenMP support (but it doesn't seem like thats relevant) - anyways

```
1>Building ComputeCpp integration header file D:/Google Drive/IM/Semester_4/ModalSynth_GPU/computecpp-sdk-master/computecpp-sdk-master/build/tests/vptr/basic_basic.cc.sycl
1>In file included from D:/Google Drive/IM/Semester_4/ModalSynth_GPU/computecpp-sdk-master/computecpp-sdk-master/tests/vptr/basic.cc:30:
1>In file included from C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\CL/sycl.hpp:1:
1>In file included from C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\CL/../SYCL/sycl.hpp:20:
1>In file included from C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\SYCL/sycl_builtins.h:27:
1>In file included from C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\SYCL/cpp_to_cl_cast.h:12:
1>In file included from C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\SYCL/deduce.h:25:
1>In file included from C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\SYCL/cl_types.h:23:
1>In file included from C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\SYCL/common.h:21:
1>C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\SYCL/include_opencl.h:27:10: fatal error: 'CL/cl.h' file not found
1>#include <CL/cl.h>
1>         ^~~~~~~~~
1>1 error generated.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(231,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code 1 beendet.
1>Die Erstellung des Projekts "basic.vcxproj" ist abgeschlossen -- FEHLER.
========== Erstellen: 0 erfolgreich, 1 fehlerhaft, 0 aktuell, 0 übersprungen ==========
```

I have added the OpenCl headers to the Additional Include Dirs in the Project Settings. See Screenshots below. I've added the compiler flag for using ptx (compute++ -sycl -sycl-target ptx64 ) - I'm on a Nvidia GTX 1650.

Why does it throw the

```
C:/Program Files/Codeplay/ComputeCpp/include\SYCL/include_opencl.h:27:10: fatal error: 'CL/cl.h' file not found
```

error - with the cmd exit code 1

```
error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code 1 beendet.
```

?

[image: VS19 include 1]

[image: VS19 include 2]

==============

**TEMPORAL SOLUTION and QUESTION 2**

I've installed the headers using Vcpkg with the `vcpkg install opencl:x64-windows` command - I however have 4 new errors that I am unable to deal with at the moment:

[image]

Something seems to be messed up regarding this path - I'm not exactly sure whats happening - what is the c1xx file good for?

Seems like the path `D:\Google Drive\IM\Semester_4\ModalSynth_GPU\computecpp-sdk-master\computecpp-sdk-master\build\tests\vptr\basic.cc` is split up

into

```
D:\Google
```

and

```
Drive\IM\Semester_4\ModalSynth_GPU\computecpp-sdk-master\computecpp-sdk-master\build\tests\vptr\basic.cc
```

Wtf? Thanks.

Here is my computecpp_info output for reference:

```
********************************************************************************

ComputeCpp Info (CE 2.0.0)

SYCL 1.2.1 revision 3

********************************************************************************


Device Info:

Discovered 1 devices matching:
  platform    : <any>
  device type : <any>

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device 0:

  Device is supported                     : UNTESTED - Vendor not tested on this OS
  Bitcode targets                         : ptx64
  CL_DEVICE_NAME                          : GeForce GTX 1650
  CL_DEVICE_VENDOR                        : NVIDIA Corporation
  CL_DRIVER_VERSION                       : 451.22
  CL_DEVICE_TYPE                          : CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
```

Comment: Do you have the OpenCL drivers installed for your machine? It looks like either that is missing or something is wrong with the installation of OpenCL.

Comment: how can i check that? On Nvidias site here they say that OpenCL support is included in the latest NVIDIA GPU drivers - i have Driver 451.22. 
How do I install OpenCL? Maybe I missed that point

Comment: computecpp_info will verify that devices can be found. Does that show the Nvidia device in the list? There are instructions on how to run that in the getting started guide.

Comment: I'd suggest trying an uninstall and reinstall of ComputeCpp just to clean things up as your paths seem to be messed up somehow. Then check computecpp_info  output on the command line see the location here: https://developer.codeplay.com/products/computecpp/ce/guides/platform-support/targeting-windows

Comment: Thanks - I just did a reinstall and ran computecpp_info - its on the list - it didnt solve my Problem (Question 2 in original post) - do you have any ide whats going on with the path there? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently SYCL didn't like the Space ' ' in the path

```
D:\Google Drive\IM\Semester_4\ModalSynth_GPU\computecpp-sdk-master\computecpp-sdk-master\build\tests\vptr\basic.cc
```

I replaced it with an underscore and it now works.

Comment: Interesting thanks. I'll raise an issue to investigate it.